# Positivity of coefficients of Ehrhart polynomial of n-Tetrahedron

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, convex-polytopes

A set of positive integers $d_1, \dots, d_n$ describe two n-dimensional closed lattice tetrahedron:
$$ T = \left\{ (x_1, \dots, x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n: \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{d_i} \leq 1 \textrm{ and all } x_i \geq 0 \right\}.$$
Let $L_T(t)$ be the Ehrhart polynomial of $T$, i.e. the number of integer lattice points in $tT$.

When are all coefficients of $L_{T}(t)$ positive?

Comment: Let me take a look at the case $n=2$ to get an idea of what one might expect. In this case the triangle $tT$ in question has vertices 
$$(td_1,0),(0,td_2),(0,0).$$
Pick's formula gives the number of points as 
$${\rm Area}+\frac 12\sharp({\rm pts ~on~the~boundary})+1
=\frac 12t^2 d_1d_2 + \frac 12t(\gcd(d_1,d_2)+d_1+d_2)+1
$$
so the coefficients are all positive.

Comment: To add some information: 1. [Pommersheim](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/pommersheim.pdf) has given an explicit formula for $n=3$ based on Dedekind sums. I can post the polynomial on request. 2. In the case that $d_1 = \dots = d_n$, then the coefficients are the absolute value of the Stirling numbers of the first kind and therefore always positive.

Comment: @LevBorisov: Thanks for the start! Any idea how to proceed from there? [This paper of Beck](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0306035v1.pdf) gives a description of all coefficients via the Residue Theorem, however I cannot derive anything about the coefficient signs.

Comment: I don't know, it may be a difficult problem. Have you tried to code it in, say, dimension three or four and just see what you get?

Comment: @LevBorisov: Yes, maybe, although everything I've tried experimentally had only positive coefficients (up to five dimensions). So I was hoping for a simple answer. In case you've got a counter example, that would be already very helpful.

Comment: $T_2$ does not have integer vertices, so it does not have an Ehrhart polynomial. Let $M$ be the least common multiple of $d_1,\dots,d_n$. You could ask for each $0\leq j<M$ whether the polynomial $p_j(t)=L_{T_2}(tM+j)$ has positive coefficients.

Comment: @RichardStanley: Yes, right. I was thinking of the periodic coefficients of the quasi polynomials, but you're right that $T_2$ won't add too much for the time being. I will take it out from the question.

Comment: I agree with Lev that this is a difficult problem, already for $n=3$. As Sebastian mentioned, one can compute these polynomials through Dedekind sums (and there generalized versions, for $n \ge 5$), but those are delicate...

Comment: @matthiasbeck Yes, the Dedekind sums look very daunting to me. I'd like to suggest a simplification (if any): For $L_T(t) = c_{n-1} t^{n-1} + \dots + c_{0} t$, my application problem is: $L_T(t) \geq c_{n-1} t^{n-1}$?